# GoRoutines, Channels with WaitGroup unexpected output

Tags: go

I looked at some code that I've wrote a long time ago, when go1.3 was released(I might be wrong). [CODE HERE](http://play.golang.org/p/t-hMZjTBqQ)

The below code used to work as expected, but now since I've update `go` to the current master version(go version devel +bd1efd5 Fri Jul 31 16:11:21 2015 +0000 darwin/amd64), the last output message `c <- "FUNC 1 DONE"` is not printed, the code works as it should on `play.golang.org`. Did I do something wrong, or this is a bug?

```
package main

import ("fmt";"sync";"time")

func test(c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  fmt.Println("EXEC FUNC 1")
  time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
  c <- "FUNC 1 DONE"
}

func test1(c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  fmt.Println("EXEC FUNC 2")
  time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
  c <- "FUNC 2 DONE"
}

func main() {
  ch := make(chan string)

  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(2)

  go test(ch, &wg)
  go test1(ch, &wg)

  go func(c chan string) {
    for txt := range c {
      fmt.Println(txt)
    }
  }(ch)

  wg.Wait()
}
```

UPDATE:

I'm not saying that, the above is the best way of doing those types of work, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Also running it in `go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64` will return the expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has always had this bug. It was only by chance that your program managed to print all messages before main exited.

To make this work correctly, I would invert where you have the `wg.Wait()` and the channel receives, so you can asynchronously close the channel. This way the receive operations are what is blocking `main`, and the channel is closed as soon as all send operations are done.

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go test(ch, &wg)
    go test1(ch, &wg)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for txt := range ch {
        fmt.Println(txt)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this issue occurs when the app is running on a single thread. go1.4 and earlier ran as GOMAXPROCS=1 by default. 1.5+ has been changed to GOMAXPROCS=NumCPU. This would explain the bug's sudden appearance.

Comment: @tidwall: no, it was only by chance that the scheduler let the last print statement through. You can test this easily by running GOMAXPROCS=1 with go1.5, which shows the same broken output (at least on my system. The result is technically non-deterministic, since there's no defined order of goroutine execution).

Comment: @JimB same for me, setting GOMAXPROCS to 1 will still output the same broken output.

Comment: @alexsmn: yes, exactly. It's not necessarily a change in GOMAXPROCS, it's a change in the runtime that is causing the execution order of goroutines to differ slightly. The original code was never correct.

Comment: @JimB: indeed I'm wrong. I'm getting the same results as you are. There's a clear bug in the code; where the chan msg is being received and the WaitGroup is being released allowing main to return, prior to the final fmt.Println.